# Overflowing item in flexbox when using truncated text

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I've got some really weird interaction between truncated text and flexboxes. I want to display multiple 'buttons' using columns which are in a div that is placed in a flexbox. The environment uses the bootstrap v5.0.1 library for styling.

When I view the webpage from a large display, it behaves as expected, but as I shrink down the display size, I see that slowly the columned div starts to overflow, and I cannot quite catch the reason for it.  As far as I knew, text truncate should have truncated the text when it wanted to wrap, but apparently, if I use text-truncate on small displays, the text does not want to truncate at the "original wrap point", but later. Weirdly, the overflowing disappears when I no longer use text-truncate, but that just makes the design much worse than it already is.

The code is the following:

```
<div class="p-1 d-flex flex-column mt-2 border rounded">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="pr-1 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div style="height: 72px; width: 72px" class="rounded justify-content-center bg-info">
            <small style="font-size: 0.5rem;">img replacement</small>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
      <div id="contact-accordion-196" aria-labelledby="headingFour" class="collapse show">
        <div class="mb-1">
          <div class="rounded border p-1 px-2">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-1">
                <div class="p-1 rounded bg-light text-truncate">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank"> amet,
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-1">
                <div class="p-1 rounded bg-light text-truncate">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank"> adipiscing sit consectetur eget
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-1">
                <div class="p-1 rounded bg-light text-truncate">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank"> lectus amet, eros
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-1">
                <div class="p-1 rounded bg-light text-truncate">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank"> semper. scelerisque. id ipsum Maecenas ipsum amet Sed elit. ipsum
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-1">
                <div class="p-1 rounded bg-light text-truncate">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank"> semper. lectus tincidunt eget eget amet vitae eros eget scelerisque.
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-1">
                <div class="p-1 rounded bg-light text-truncate">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank"> vitae adipiscing lectus
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-1">
                <div class="p-1 rounded bg-light text-truncate">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank"> tincidunt, Sed semper semper. Lorem sit elit. adipiscing tincidunt
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-1">
                <div class="p-1 rounded bg-light text-truncate">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank"> velit amet scelerisque, amet
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-1">
                <div class="p-1 rounded bg-light text-truncate">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank"> amet scelerisque. amet,
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-1">
                <div class="p-1 rounded bg-light text-truncate">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank"> ut, arcu semper tincidunt lectus
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-1">
                <div class="p-1 rounded bg-light text-truncate">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank"> Lorem
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-1">
                <div class="p-1 rounded bg-light text-truncate">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank"> arcu Sed lectus Lorem semper scelerisque, lectus scelerisque, scelerisque. semper
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can run this snippet [here](https://playcode.io/1712721) (playcode link).

I have realised that the problem probably has something to do with the image that is present, but it is imperative for every element to be present. Wrapping the elements works, but wastes a ton of space. I want to utilise the space after the image (which is a div - `img replacement` in the code) to display these columns.

The weird thing is that this problem mainly occurs when viewing on small displays, but not necessarily, it is like it depends on the text width (which I was certain text-truncate should have taken care of).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!